# How to keep a cloned table header stick as the page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pUstKXJz

When you scroll past 100pixel, there is an alert and also the cloned header is displayed. How can I modify the JQuery so the cloned header sticks to the top of the page as I scroll down.

It is currently commented out because it is not working.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Here is the image:

[image]

What the output is based on the answer listed below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to move the `<tr class="showOnlyAfterScroll">..</tr>` outside of the current table and wrap it in another table just before the actual `<table class="tblPrint">..</table>`, and also you have to set the "showOnlyAfterScroll" class to the new `<table>` tag instead of the `<tr>`, like so:

```
<!--your new table-->
<table class="tblPrint showOnlyAfterScroll">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="mainTR">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!--your current table-->
<table class="tblPrint">
    <tbody>...etc
```

Now add the following css:

```
.showOnlyAfterScroll{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Finally, you have to adjust the width % of the all five columns so they are same in both tables:

```
.mainTR > th:nth-child(1){ width: 15%; }
.mainTR > th:nth-child(2){ width: 15%; }
.mainTR > th:nth-child(3){ width: 20%; }
.mainTR > th:nth-child(4){ width: 30%; }
.mainTR > th:nth-child(5){ width: 20%; }
```

but make sure the total width of columns is 100%.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you are doing. I will give it a try and see what happens. So inside the javascript `tab_text` variable, create the `showOnlyAfterScroll` table first. Is my `scrollto` function correct?

Comment: Everything else seems fine! just make sure your html is arranged like the one I wrote on the answer.. you have to move that sticky row to a new table.

Comment: Because i am creating table with JavaScript i dont have a tbody instead just tr. Is that fine? Thanks

Comment: Yep! But while its easier done than said in this case, here's the modified [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KPRQSKQX)

Comment: Nevermind. I see what is happening. I can leave the code commented out. Thanks. It is as close to the width as I can get I am guessing? :)

Comment: One quick note, can you please tell me why the print isn't working in IE. Works fine in Chrome/FF.

Comment: Tested it on IE 11.0 and works fine for me! Couldn't test on older versions though.
Btw, did you get the fixed code from my pastebin link? It is the complete code modified to your requests, simply copy and paste it.

Comment: I have updated my question with two screenshots showing the issue. Even though their width is both 15%, they are out of place and also every other column. Any idea how I can resolve it? BTW thanks for getting me this far, it helped a lot.

Comment: Can you see this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/hYZZnwBK I wonder why it is not matching up...

Comment: In case you didn't resolve the issue yet, here's a pastebin of a fixed code. Just copy and paste it ! http://pastebin.com/0DQpR4y9